# select query with date type in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

iam writing sql query in oracle database ,but there are table name exist ,but also oracle resualts with error thats the table or view not found

another issue that iam writing this query

```
select * from Table_name where DDATE="30-05-2014;

but id doesn't return anything how to write where with date type
```

Comment: You missed a `"` in your query.

Comment: For the first error you haven't shown the table name you're using or why you think it exists; do you maybe have quoted mixed-case object names? For the second you should specify your date format, but since it isn't erroring, do the values on the column have a time component maybe?

Answer (score 3):

as @Alex Poole said.. Use the TO_DATE() function as:

```
select * from your_table where date_column = TO_DATE('01/01/2014' , 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

But make sure the your "date_column" a DATE type column.

Another point to consider is, if the column contains the TIME too (ex: 11/30/2012 10:00:00 AM), Use

```
select * from your_table where TRUNC(date_column) = TO_DATE('01/01/2014' , 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

this will only compare the date fraction and give you the results depending on that.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use a DATE literal instead:

```
select * from Table_name where VHFDATE= DATE '2014-05-30';
```

Or, if the date value is being supplied from a UI or from somewhere else, use a bind variable:

```
select * from Table_name where VHFDATE= :in_vhf_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

These might be some of the reasons for getting those error.

1 ) If you get a table or view does not exists error , it means you may not have sufficient **privilege** on that table.

2) Use a date format like to_date() for date datatypes.

```
 select * from your_table where to_date(date_column,'DD-MON-YYYY')='30-MAR-2012';
```

3) Check whether you have data for that particular date. You can use a simple **GROUP BY** to check for the number of record for that data.

```
 select count(*),date_column from your_table group by date_column order by date_column desc;
```

Comment: Better to use a date literal like in Jeffrey Kemp's answer.  `Mar` is not always a valid month abbreviation.

Comment: That depends your requirement. I have edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: I think jonearles meant that it's not a valid month abbreviation in every language, so relying on `MAR` (or `Mar` if you use `Mon`) is not safe as clients may not be using English. You can use the optional `nlsparam` argument to override that but it's simpler to avoid it when possible. You're also converting what already seems to be a date (`date_column`) to another date, and then comparing with a string, which still does multiple implicit date conversions. Maybe you meant to use `to_char`; but it's better to convert the string to a date for comparison, so indexes can still be used.